# How to add providers, service and interceptor only for gift card module in angular?

Tags: angular, module, angular-http-interceptors, http-caching, angular-providers

I am implementing caching only for gift card module and I have created http-cache.service and cache interceptor.When I add the service in app.module.ts it works but I need to implement this separately only for giftcard.When I do separately for gift card it doesn't work.This is my code

giftcard-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { GiftcardComponent } from './list/giftcard.component';
import { GiftcardtransactionComponent } from './giftcardtransaction/giftcardtransaction.component';
 const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: GiftcardComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'sales',
      component: GiftcardtransactionComponent,
      data: { breadcrumb: "Sales" }
    }   
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
  
})
export class GiftCardRoutingModule { }
```

giftcard.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { GiftcardComponent } from './list/giftcard.component';
import { GiftcardtransactionComponent } from './giftcardtransaction/giftcardtransaction.component';
import { GiftCardRoutingModule } from './giftcard-routing.module';
import { CacheInterceptor } from '../helper/interceptors/cache.interceptor';
import { HttpCacheService } from '../helper/services/cache/http-cache.service';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from "@angular/common/http";
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        GiftCardRoutingModule,
        RouterModule        
    ],
    declarations: [
        GiftcardComponent,
        GiftcardtransactionComponent        
  ],
  providers: [
    HttpCacheService,{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CacheInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
})
export class GiftCardModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Which error occurs when you reference the service in your module?

Is you module only importet once?

I also identified an issue with your Routing declaration. You already imported
**RouterModule** in your ***giftcard-routing.module.ts*** and exported it ther.

You don't need to import **Router Module** separately in your ***giftcard.module.ts*** This can also cause some issues

Comment: I don't get any error.The caching does not work when I remove it from app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can inject UserService anywhere in your application.

The service itself is a class that the CLI generated and that's decorated with @Injectable(). By default, this decorator has a providedIn property, which creates a provider for the service. In this case, providedIn: 'root' specifies that Angular should provide the service in the root injector.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
}
```

It's also possible to specify that a service should be provided in a particular @NgModule. For example, if you don't want UserService to be available to applications unless they import a UserModule you've created, you can specify that the service should be provided in the module:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserModule } from './user.module';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: UserModule,
})
export class UserService {
}
```